# Lua SDK for IntelliJ on a Linux system?

Tags: intellij-idea, lua, sdk

Trying to set up IntelliJ IDEA with the [Lua plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5055-lua). This requires me to direct it to the location of a Lua SDK. All instructions I have been able to find for this are on a Windows system, pointing to a specific directory in `Program Files`. I am running a Linux system. I've built and installed Lua 5.3.4 (newest version at time of writing) from source, but as far as I can tell that doesn't include any equivalent to the SDK needed – it just drops a variety of necessary files in `/usr/local/{bin,include,lib,man/man1}` and creates two empty directories `/usr/local/{lib,share}/lua/5.3`.

Am I missing something conceptual? Do I need to get something else (the existence of which I have been unable to confirm)? Should I just give up on this and find another IDE? The plugin seems to come with two SDKs, `Kahlua` and `LuaJ`, but I don't know how well either of these match up to either standard Lua or LuaJit, which are what I would be using.

Answer (score 2):

This is assuming you are using [this Lua plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5055-lua) for IntelliJ:

If you have installed Lua via DNF or yum simply guide IntelliJ to `/urs/bin` and it'll find it. (I assume this also works for other installers like apt or brew.)

It looks like the SDK is just looking for two files lua and luac which both live in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Go to file > project structure > SDKs > `+` button > LUA SDK > Select `/usr/bin` > OK